# Background Image not appearing properly in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a table cell in which i have to set a background image, the background image i have basically contains 3 parts 1st is the top part (which comes out fine) 2nd is the bottom part which also appears fine and the 3rd that is the middle portion is a sprite which has a height of 57px.
This image(3rd) can be repeated in the x direction but i need to somehow stretch it in Y direction.
In firefox this image fits perfectly using the `background-size:contain` property but this property does not work for IE.

So I'm setting the cell height to 57px (which is the height of the image) and repeating the image only in x direction. The HTML i have looks something like this:

```
<table>
     <tr>
        <td>
               <ul>    //for some reason i'm using li tags for setting the images
                  <li class="img1"></li>
                  <li class="img3"></li> //the middle img which is creating the problem
                  <li class="img2"></li>
               </ul>
         </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the css i have written for the class "img3"

```
.img3 {
        background-image: url("../images/PictorialViewBoxes/Blue_Middle.jpg");
        list-style: none;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: Bolder;
        text-align: center;
        width: 160px;
        word-wrap: normal;
        text-transform: capitalize;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding-left:10px;
        padding-right:10px;
        min-height: 57px;
        max-height: 57px;
        font-family: arial;
        background-repeat:repeat-x;
        overflow-y:hidden;
        }
```

The height of the cell containing these background images is 'auto' Now this works fine is all browsers even IE8 but not in IE7 here is the result in IE8 and IE7 :-

[image: Output in IE8]       [image: Output in IE7]

I don't understand why this white gap is coming in IE7!!

**Link to JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qYNAD/8/**

[image: img1]
[image: img3]
[image: img2]

Comment: Does the height need to be auto? If not, I'd recommend setting a fixed height. Also, try adding `display: block;` :)

Comment: Can you [reproduce the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/) so we can see it?

Comment: @thirtydot "reproduce" in the sense??

Comment: @peduarte no the height need not be auto, i'll try making it fixed and also add display:block

Comment: Can you make a test case demonstrating the problem so that it's easier to debug? http://jsfiddle.net/ or http://jsbin.com/

Comment: @thirtydot: I've created one with his submitted code but does not reproduce the problem - http://jsfiddle.net/qYNAD/2/

Comment: @thirtydot : the image u see in the background is a set of 3 different images 1 for the top,bottom and a sprite for the middle which is being repeated in the x direction. The problem is only with IE7 in all other browsers it works perfectly!!

Comment: @My Head Hurts: Exactly. That's why I asked him to provide a test case that *reproduces the problem* :)

Comment: If it helps, you can upload the images here: http://imgur.com/

Comment: @thirtydot : can't upload images to imgur, i'll edit my post add the images to the question itself if possible can you upload them and update the image urls on jsfiddle (i have added the css for the rest of the 2 images also there) thnks

Comment: here is the updated jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/qYNAD/8/

Comment: My answer should fix your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your fix:

```
ul {
    overflow: hidden;
}

li {
    clear:both;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: thanks it works...but can u tell me what exactly was the problem

Comment: If you look at this: [http://jsfiddle.net/peduarte/qYNAD/10/](http://jsfiddle.net/peduarte/qYNAD/10/) you can see that IE7 adds a space between img3 and img2. By floating the `li` and clearing the floats with `overflow: hidden` it fixes the issue. Can't explain better than this, perhaps someone else can?

Comment: i guess i got ur point :P. hey for the same code is it possible to stretch the image in y-direction. Because in case i need longer boxes i can't repeat the image in y-direction (because of the gradient thing) instead i have to somehow stretch it. In firefox this was pretty simple using the background-size property but it doesn't work in IE any suggestions??

Comment: You have to make a bigger version of the gradient :(

Comment: oh so if the gradient height is 57px i can only use it for boxes of height 57px :( :( that sucks!!.....any way thanks for your answer (while i wait here for the day when IE is fully compatible with CSS3) :P

Answer (score 0):

Increase the height to fit the image and make sure you´re using a DOCTYPE, this is often causing different a behavior in IE.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>...
```

It might also me the `line-height` that´s causing your problems. Read more at http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/line-height

Comment: the height of the element inside which i'm placing the image is exactly the same as the image height!.....and yes i'm using proper DOCTYPE declarations! (ur answer doesn't make any sense, if this was the problem it wouldn't have even worked in IE8!!)

Comment: Edited my answer, try laborating with the line-height.

Comment: kindly check the "compatibility" section of the link u've shared it says its not compatible with IE7 which actually is my problem, so sorry this too doesn't solve the issue....any way thanks for your time though some one else has answered this question and his solution actually worked go through it once......cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding af transparent border to the dom element with the background image:

Css before fix:

```
li.icontwo { 
    padding:7px 0px 25px 70px; 
    background:url(/images/icon2.png) left top no-repeat;
}
```

Css after fix:

```
li.icontwo {
    padding:7px 0px 25px 70px; 
    background:url(/images/icon2.png) left top no-repeat;
    border:1px solid transparent;
}
```

I know its a hack but it works.